# Filter out all normalized words from the PySpark dataframe column

Tags: pyspark

I have a column of sentences in the PySpark dataframe with normalized text like so:

**{product} {number} {number} was purchased on {date} and returned**

Normalized text is in the marked by {}, like {number} or {date}

I need to drop all normalized words, so that the sentence becomes like so:

**was purchased on and returned**

Any suggestions?

Started writing, but then got stuck:

data.filter(data.sentence.contains('{'))

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way is to use replace on each field with a regex that captures everyting in between {} and replace it with an empty string.

```
data = [(1, '{product} {number} {number} was purchased on {date} and 
returned')]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ["ix", "string"])
# here I created a new column called new_col replacing everything
# that matches the regular expression with an empty string 
df = df.withColumn('new_col', F.regexp_replace(F.col("string"), "\\{(.*?)\}", ""))
df.show()
```

Output:

```
+---+--------------------+--------------------+
| ix|              string|             new_col|
+---+--------------------+--------------------+
|  1|{product} {number...|   was purchased ...|
+---+--------------------+--------------------+
```

Comment: This is good, thank you very much. How would you not replace the column, but add a column instead, so that original column remains.

Comment: If you don't want to create a column with a new name just use the same name of the column. `df = df.withColumn('string', F.regexp_replace(F.col("string"), "\\{(.*?)\}", ""))`.